# Passing text with bookmarks into AWS Polly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-polly

I can call Polly service fine with plain text.  However what I want to do now is pass it text with bookmarks in it ( As I want to control where Polly puts the timimg ionformation ) but can't see how to pass this into Polly?

```
        SynthesizeSpeechRequest synthesizeSpeechRequest = new SynthesizeSpeechRequest()
            .withOutputFormat(OutputFormat.Json)
            .withSpeechMarkTypes(SpeechMarkType.Ssml)
            .withVoiceId(VoiceId.Joanna)
            .withText("<Mark> This is a sample <Mark> text to be synthesized");

        SynthesizeSpeechResult synthesizeSpeechResult = client.synthesizeSpeech(synthesizeSpeechRequest);
```

but I always get the following error

```
 Exception caught: com.amazonaws.services.polly.model.SsmlMarksNotSupportedForTextTypeException: SSML Speech marks are not supported for this text type (Service: AmazonPolly; Status Code: 400; Error Code: SsmlMarksNotSupportedForTextTypeException; Request ID: 79daa5cc-0ce0-11e8-a64d-ef4f40dcae18)
```

Comment: Do you need to use `withTextType()` to set the text type to SSML?

Comment: Yes,  that was it.  I can't accept comment as an answer so if you want to change it to an answer I can accept that then ... Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks, @MayoMan.  I just went for a dive in the docs and that seemed like the missing piece, but I'm not really a Java expert... so, please, feel free to go ahead and post the answer, below.  Show enough detail and code to help future visitors solve the same problem, and I'll gladly give you an upvote.